# Generating string primary keys with sequence in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, primary-key, sequence

Generating random string keys in SQA is relatively simple, something like:

```
request_id = Column(String, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex, primary_key=True)
```

However, I need to to get `request_id` have format like `DIVISION_ABC_REQUEST_223` (this is because PK is also supposed to be good for human consumption -- that key will be sent around in emails, copied/pasted, etc, but it also should be usable for regular SQA/SQL queries as a typical PK), with integer suffixes ideally following a normal (ordinal) sequence.

(the backend DB is Postgres)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, if a bit wasteful:

```
class WorkPackage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'work_package'
    int_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    wp_prefix = Column(Unicode, default=u'DIVISION_ABC_REQUEST_', primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Unicode)

    @hybrid_property
    def wp_id(self):
        return self.wp_prefix + str(self.int_id)

    @wp_id.expression
    def wp_id(cls):
        return cls.wp_prefix.concat(cls.int_id)
```

`wp_id.expression` uses `concat` (a `ColumnOperator` that produces SQL concatenation operator `||`).

It works in the sense of automatic PK creation in desired order and for querying by the `wp_id` attribute.

However, the silly aspect is that obviously there's a single column filled with the same prefix over and over.